# Returning a value based on max sum and one more condition

Tags: indexing, sum, max, excel-formula, vlookup

```
      A         B         C
1     #         Code    Quantity
2     1001      1         10
3     1001      1         20
4     1002      2         10
5     1003      2         10
6     1003      2         10
7     1003      2         10
8     1004      1         40
9     1005      3         20
```

I want to display in A11: The # in A, who has the Code 1 in B, and who has the largest quantity in C.

I figure it requires Index Match Max Sumif and Vlookup, but i've no idea how to put them together(

Thanks to anyone for any kind of suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do

```
=INDEX(A1:A9,MAX(ROW(C1:C9)*(C1:C9=1)*(D1:D9=MAX($D$1:$D$9))))
```

This is an array formula you have to validate with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

[EDIT] The final solution that worked for Tauren:

```
=INDEX(A1:A9,MAX(ROW(B1:B9)*(B1:B9=1)*(C1:C9=MAX(C1:C9))))
```

---

And the french version for whoever would need it:

```
=INDEX(A1:A9;MAX(LIGNE(C1:C9)*(C1:C9=1)*(D1:D9=MAX($D$1:$D$9))))
```

Comment: Thank you, Jmax! I'm afraid it gives me 1001, whereas i need 1004. Only 1001 and 1004 have the code "1", and among the two, 1001 has the sum 30 in column C, while 1004 has 40. Therefore the answer should be 1004.

Comment: @user1205756: are you sure? it worked for me and I get `8` (or I get `1004` when I change the index to `B1:B9`). Would you mind checking again?

Comment: Hey, JMax. I suspected that the columns in your formula might have been different from what i needed, so I changed the formula to =index(a1:a9,max(row(b1:b9)*(b1:b9=1)*(c1:c9=max(c1:c9))))  and then it gave me 1004!

Comment: Thank you for you help, JMax! I have a humble suggestion about your answer: your formula is correct, and i think it might be a little easier to copy-paste if you change the column referrences as i did in my comment, though it's totally ok if you would like to leave it as it is) at least i got the point! Thanks again!

Comment: @Tauren: I edited my answer with your working solution. Yet, I would suggest you add static references to the last part of your formula